# db2 concatenated rows displaying whitespace

Tags: sql, replace, db2

I have a column in a DB2 table where the rows of data consist of two strings, `string1` and `string2`. These have a number of whitespace characters in between them, which I'm trying to remove.

When I run the following, I see the expected result, which is `string1` `string2`.

> SELECT REPLACE(COLUMN,' ','') FROM Source_Table;

However when I try to insert the cleansed rows into a new table, the data still contains whitespace between `string1` and `string2`.

> INSERT INTO Target_Table (Column)
>
> SELECT REPLACE(Column,' ','') FROM Source_Table;

Comment: I try these, everything works correctly, could you provide sample data in your table. And what is your column's data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably declared your column as `CHAR` and DB2 is filling unused space in your column with spaces. That's by design.

If you want to avoid this behavior you should declare the column as `VARCHAR`

Also in your `SELECT` you should use the `TRIM` or `RTRIM` function for removing the withespaces instead of `REPLACE()`

Comment: you're right I have used `CHAR`, I'll try it wil `VARCHAR`. Thanks!

Comment: you'll still need `TRIMR()` if the original data remains `CHAR`.  Otherwise you'd need to change the original to `VARCHAR` and make sure that the data is trimmed when loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use trim / rtrim like above said you, or strip function